# Skinned Panel content offset in Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Here is the problem. I've created custom RectangularBorder and set it as border skin for TitleWindow. After this manipulation inner content of window is starting at 0,0 point of it. How could I set offset of it?

**Just setting top padding does not work because scroll bar still begins from the top of the window after this manipulation.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For programmatic skin it went out pretty simple. One should override function get borderMetrics to do so:

```
public override function get borderMetrics():EdgeMetrics
{
    var borderThickness:Number = getStyle("borderThickness");
    var cornerRadius:Number = getStyle("cornerRadius");         
    var headerHeight:Number = getStyle("headerHeight");

    return new EdgeMetrics(
        borderThickness,  
        borderThickness + headerHeight,
        borderThickness,
        borderThickness);           
 }
```

Comment: I wish this was clear from the documentation! Thanks so much Artem.

Comment: Yes, me too. I've recently started to read their code much more often, thin reading their documentation. It's messier, but helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of problems with trying to skin panels in Flex 3, and TitleWindow inherits from Panel.

[This](http://dougmccune.com/blog/2008/01/12/calling-bullshit-on-a-resolved-flex-bug/) is the best explanation I've seen. (I'm not the same Glenn referenced in the italics :)).

Answer (score -1):

try to use padding-top , padding-left etc as a style for your TitleWindow